# IntelXDK Cordova Mobile Apps : issue on hiding input when soft keyboards up

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mobile, intel-xdk

I am new in hybrid mobile apps development. I am developing apps using IntelXDK with cordova & html5. My issue is when I build my apps and install in mobile, my input area is hidden under soft keys(when clicked for type). It should scroll up automatically when clicks to type and soft key arrives.

I have already tried `<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />` in my config file. But no hope.

Now I am stuck. Can you please give me any solution or any idea to make me out from here.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Ionic Cordova Keyboard Plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard). You'll have to write some code to make it work, but this generally fixes the problems you are describing for most people. It's available via the Cordova Registry as `ionic-plugin-keyboard`.

Comment: I have tried. But I dont know why this dont make any response on events.